# ExpressJS next(error) vs return next(error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What's difference between
next(error) and
return next(error)

How to throws Business Exceptions in ExpressJS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `return` isn't needed by Express. `next(error)` is sufficient for it.

```
function foo(req, res, next) {
    next(new Error());
}
```

But, the `return` can be used to also stop the execution of the current `function`, allowing `next(error)` to more closely resemble a `throw` statement.

```
function foo(req, res, next) {
    return next(new Error());

    console.log("This is unreachable code and won't be logged.");
}
```

Comment: So without a 'return' does execution continue in that function after the call to next() finishes?

Comment: @DanielM Yeah. `next()` shouldn't interrupt a route handler, such as `foo()` here, on its own. The `return` is responsible for that. They can just be used together to both raise an `Error` within Express and exit the current handler immediately after.

Comment: What if we have multiple middleware and we return next(error) in one of them ?